# List and uniform access principle

Tags: scala, uniform-interface

I have the following code, and I was wondering why the `list.head.effects =` part is necessary here. To my understanding, uniform access princile says that the list should be returned by just the `list.head.effects`, at which point I could access the list. But to make the assignment actually work, I need to have it as it is below. 
Would it be that it evaluates the `Entrance :: list.head.effects` but does not assign it anywhere? Am I still too deep in the mutable world?

```
def addEntrance(list: List[Tile]) = list.head.effects = Entrance :: list.head.effects

case class Tile(x: Int, y: Int) {
  var effects: List[_ >: Effect] = List()
}

case class Entrance extends Effect
```

In any case, is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::` creates a new list where the left argument is prepended to the list on the right. This does not change or assign anything. An immutable solution without the `var` could be:

```
case class Tile(x: Int, y: Int, effects: List[_ >: Effect] = List())

case class Entrance extends Effect

def addEntrance(list: List[Tile)) = list match {
  case Tile(x,y,effects) :: tail => Tile(x,y,Entrance() :: effects) :: tail
  case Nil => ...
}
```

Here `addEntrance` returns an updated list, which is the way to work with immutable lists.

By the way: Using `.head` on a list is only for special cases because usually you don't know whether the list has at least one item. So using pattern matching is a better approach here.